# converting datetime to string with T07:00:00.0000000Z

Tags: c#, .net, azure-table-storage

I am attempting to query table storage by generating the following query:

```
var date = new DateTime(1954, 9, 7);
var timequery = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, date.ToString());
```

I am getting a bad request when simply doing `date.ToString()`

The string that I need would be in the following format: `1954-09-07T07:00:00.0000000Z`

**How do I convert a regular DateTime to be a string in the specified format?**

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("o");`  This would generate an ISO-8601 compliant datetime string.

Comment: The Visual Studio tags should only be used when your question is *about* Visual Studio, not a code-related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Var date = new DateTime(1954,7,0,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc);

Var stringDate = date.ToUniversalTime().ToString(“o”);

Gives you the required result as 
1954-09-07T00:00:00.0000000Z

Comment: Var date = new DateTime(1954,9,7,0,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc);